# join same table twice and get the results of rows

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i have table like wp_term_relationships

`object_id  term_taxonomy_id    term_order
     194            2           0
     194            7           0
     194            8           0
     194            38          0
     194            44          0
     194            59          0
     194            100         0
     194            101         0`

My question is: I need a query like the term_taxonomy_id of 44 and 8.

44 is country id and 8 is course id. I need query when am selecting country id and course id, than display an particular country having this paricular course.

7 is parent course id. 38 is country parent id.

I have written a query like this:

```
SELECT object_id 
FROM   wp_term_relationships
WHERE  term_taxonomy_id IN ( 44, 8 )
```

its displaying the country having all the coursee and course having all the countries. But I need only particular country having the particular course in its cities.

Comment: Please add some "expected output". From what you wrote I am really not sure what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

How about a "self join":

```
SELECT a.object_id
    FROM wp_term_relationships AS a
    JOIN wp_term_relationships AS b  ON a.object_id = b.object_id
    WHERE a.term_taxonomy_id = 44
      AND b.term_taxonomy_id =  8;
```

Comment: Thanks to all...
One more question is there..
i have query its searching without city, am selecting course and country its displaying the particular course having particular country and all the cities of that country, its working fine. But problem is when am entering same course for same city twice and searching its displaying one query is fine another query its displaying the name of last city in that particular country and id of that city what is the issue.in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a `GROUP BY` aggregation and make sure the `COUNT(1)` is 2

Since you asked for two specific `term_taxonomy_id` values, `COUNT(1)` needs to be 2

```
SELECT   object_id 
FROM     wp_term_relationships
WHERE    term_taxonomy_id IN ( 44, 8 )
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2;
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**